# Regex on a substring

Tags: regex

Is it possible to create a regex that only evaluates the first n number of characters in a string?

For example, given the strings:

```
Line 1: The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
Line 2: There was another fox that was not so quick.
```

I need a regex that only searches for the word `quick` within the first 15 characters.  Such that line1 would match, but line2 would not match.

I'm interested in a single regex without combining with other commands, such as `cut -c1-15`, or something similar.

I understand that regex 'lookarounds' might be a possible solution, but can't seem to find anything that allows referencing position from the start of the input string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can quantify (with a range) a "dot anything" wildcard token and anchor the pattern to start of string to achieve this:

```
^.{1,15}quick
```

[regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/bH1pRg/1/)

Comment: but the regex fail when `quick` place start of the string.

Comment: yeah it would be `{0,14}` _technically_

Comment: I made your answer the accepted one.  We can substitute the value to be whatever is required.  Thank you.

Comment: One more followup...this solution technically provides a match no further away from the front than _n_ characters.  Not _within_ the first _n_ characters. But the numbers can be adjusted to achieve the desired effect.